# Why is this a bad hash function?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm currently covering hashing and hash tables and I'm wondering why something like the following is considered a bad hash function (pseudocode):

```
function hash(String_t word, Int table_size)
    i = randomly generated number with 0<i<table_size 
    j = ASCII code of the first letter of word

    return i * j % table_size
```

Assuming that the value of `i` could be stored during function invocations to achieve consistency (for example using the `static` keyword in C to store the value of `i` within the function scope), why is this a bad hash function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good hash function should work well for various input sizes, with only the condition that the table size is a constant times bigger than the number of inputs.  This does not meet that criteria for a few reasons:

1. The hash value is determined only by the first letter.  Hence, the total number of possible hash values is bounded by the number of possible first letters, which is small.  Choosing a large table size for a large number of inputs has no effect: you will still get heaps of collisions.
2. Since first letters of words are very far from being uniformly distributed, you will have a lot of collisions. At least use all letters of the word when defining your function, but you really need more than that advice to rescue this construct.
3. Define d = gcd(i, table size).  In some cases, d will be greater than 1, and in those cases, only one in every d elements of the table will have a chance to be populated: the others will be wasted space (and hence more collisions).  That is, only 0, d, 2d, 3d, ...  Could possibly be a hash value.  At least restrict to values of i with d=1 to prevent these degenerate cases.
4. i multiplied by the largest value of j will occasionally be smaller than the table size (when i is small) implying that the top end of the table will never get touched.  More wasted space.

People usually try to come up with hash functions that work well in general and that you can prove something good about them.  Here you have something intended for a very specific case and what is most visible to me is the negative cases, so very very doubtful that you can prove anything positive about this construct.

Comment: "the hash value is determined only by the first letter". Isnt the hash value determined by both the first letter AND the random value? Also, what do you mean by d=gcd(i, table size)?

Comment: @PythonNewb: depends upon how you look at it!  The way I was viewing it, the random value is chosen at the beginning and then fixed.  After that value is fixed, two words are going to collide if and only if they have the same first letter.  Gcd is greatest common divisor.  This property comes from modular arithmetic.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be an open ended question for students to come up with as many reasons as they can why this is a bad hash function. @JavascriptLoser Consider what happens if the table is size 1000 and the i is 500, then all values will hash to a multiple of 500 (0 or 500 in the table - only 2 hash values!). You want i and size values to be coprime.